# Comparison between ordinary products and tensor products

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

My question is quite simple, I didn't understand this comparison, why the first lines in this example implies the red ones:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: The red text does not really claim anything, so it is not `implied' in the usual sense. It is a teacher's attempt at a description.

Comment: Just understand that tensor product is multilinear

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, this underlines lines are an attempt at explaining what is going it. Formally, this may correspond to the fact that there is a natural map $R[X] \times R[Y] \to R[T]$ given by $(f(X), g(Y)) \mapsto f(T)g(T)$ and a natural map $R[X] \times R[Y] \to R[X] \otimes_R R[Y] = R[X,Y]$ given by $(f(X), g(Y)) \mapsto f(X)g(Y)$.

Comment: Thank you, now everything is clear.